# Probability of getting 50 or more consecutive 'successes'

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I'm having troubling approaching this problem: finding the probability of 50 or more consecutive successes in a row when p = 0.98.

I was thinking of using a binomial probability distribution but I don't believe there would be a fixed number of trials in this case? Any other way to approach this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking of the first 50  being successes, or a *streak* of 50 successes, which is certain to occur somewhere if trials are unlimited!

Comment: 50 successes in a row or more, so yes a streak of 50 successes or more!

Comment: As I have already commented, if an unlimited number of trials is allowed $Pr = 1$ !